# How to apply text/color formatting to multi index Python Chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a chart with a simple yes/no indication (in this case, using seaborn's heatmap), but with multiple indexes--the hierarchy of which I establish with calling the MultiIndex.from_arrays method. The code listed below, which pulls from the example data listed in the link below, produces this heatmap: [CurrentGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPIrk.png)

What is the easiest way to 1) Delete the outermost index labels ("Type of Category....", "None-None") 2) Change the display options and/or color formatting of the next inner index labels? (Category A, Category B, Loc1, Loc2, Loc3)

Currently, the way they are displayed is not very easy on the eyes; I'd like to make it so each label's text in this layer only shows up once and is centered along the rows/columns that were matched in the MultiIndex.from_arrays method, rather than spliced onto the beginning of each entry. If possible, I'd also like to put a different background color underneath each of these "sections" (Category A, Category B, Loc1, Loc2, Loc3) so that they appear more distinct to the eye on the graph.

Is there an easy way to do this sort of editing with heatmap/Seaborn, or is this something I would have to make from scratch? Any help on this is appreciated, as I'm still rather green with this.

http://www.filedropper.com/heatmapdata

EDIT: added sample data as text below, before code

```
Type of Category  Variables  Division 01  Division 02  Division 03  Division 04  Division 05  Division 06  Division 07 \\
Category A        V1         0            1            1            0            0            0            1           \\
Category A        V2         1            1            1            0            0            0            1           \\
Category A        V3         1            1            1            0            0            1            1           \\
Category A        V4         0            0            1            1            1            1            0           \\
Category A        V5         0            1            1            1            0            0            0           \\
Category A        V6         1            1            1            1            0            0            1           \\
Category B        V7         1            0            0            1            0            0            1          



import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

metrics = pd.read_excel(r'EnterYourFileLocationHere\Heatmap data.xlsx',   sheet_name='Example_Data')
metrics.set_index([metrics.columns[0], metrics.columns[1]], inplace=True)
metrics.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Loc1', 'Loc1', 'Loc1', 'Loc2',
                                          'Loc2', 'Loc3', 'Loc3'], 
                                         ['Division 01', 'Division 02', 
                                          'Division 03', 'Division 04',
                                          'Divsion 05', 'Division06',
                                          'Division07']])
graph = sns.heatmap(metrics, annot=True, fmt = "d", linewidth=0.5, cmap="Blues", cbar=False)
```

Comment: See [Pandas: Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an example of decorating the background of the label, so I've tried to show the category names as an example of visualization in the annotations.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# metrics = pd.read_excel(r'EnterYourFileLocationHere\Heatmap data.xlsx',   sheet_name='Example_Data')
metrics.set_index([metrics.columns[0], metrics.columns[1]], inplace=True)
metrics.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Loc1', 'Loc1', 'Loc1', 'Loc2',
                                          'Loc2', 'Loc3', 'Loc3'], 
                                         ['Division 01', 'Division 02', 
                                          'Division 03', 'Division 04',
                                          'Divsion 05', 'Division06',
                                          'Division07']])
graph = sns.heatmap(metrics, annot=False, fmt = "d", linewidth=0.5, cmap="Blues", cbar=False)

for y in range(metrics.shape[1]):
    for x in range(metrics.shape[0]):
        if metrics.iloc[x,y] == 1:
            graph.annotate(metrics.columns[y][0]+'\n '+metrics.columns[y][1][-2:], xy = (y+0.25, x+0.75), size=12, color="#ffd700")
```

[image]